# When will Dojo 2.0 be released?

Tags: dojo

I have Used Dojo 1.0, but I have some version related questions:

- When will Dojo 2.0 be released?
- Also is Dojo 1.5 the latest?

Comment: Here is [Dojo 2.0 migration guide](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/migration-2.0 "Dojo 2.0 migration guide"). Some elements can be used now with the current release.

Comment: That migration guide no longer applies. Dojo 2.0 is now a completely different animal. https://dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.4.2 is the latest version: http://dojotoolkit.org/download/
This was released on March 10, 2010

Even the dev branch is still 1.4.2-based: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.4.2/

There is not an announced release date for 2.0 as of now.

Comment: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/ gives you a good, quick overview of the various current versions.

Answer (score 5):

As I see, 1.6.1 is the latest release...

> http://download.dojotoolkit.org/

Comment: well then, this thread accepted answer should be change regularly :)

Answer (score 4):

At this time there is no fixed date for 2.0 but late 2012/early 2013 is what I've read is the target.

1.7.2 is the current version with 1.8 scheduled for July 15, 2012.

You can see the schedule here: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/roadmap

Answer (score 3):

Keeping this thread alive...

Version 1.10 is right around the corner (check the date of this post).

Currently, you can use http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/category/announcements to see what's happening.

**UPDATE (2016)**:  Here is a [roadmap](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap/) to Dojo 2:

Answer (score 2):

Now 1.7 is the latest release ... :)

http://dojotoolkit.org/

Answer (score 1):

Dojo 1.9 is now latest: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.9

Dojo 2.0 might get out next year (2014).

Answer (score 1):

Fall 2015... "Our goal is to release Dojo 2 this [fall!](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap/)"

Answer (score 0):

1.8.1 is now the latest release.  They're looking at 2013 for the 2.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

As wikipedia says:-

Dojo 1.9.1 is the latest release (on 14-June-2013)..
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit

Can download from 
http://dojotoolkit.org/download/

We can get more detail on 
http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/dojo-1-9-released

and its expected to release dojo 2.0 by the end of 2013...